# Add dylib file in xamarin ios project

Tags: vidyo

When am making xamarin ios project and add dylib file it working fine with app but when i m trying to do it with app store iTunes doesn't allow me to upload that standalone vidyo.dylib file.

Comment: Please add more details

Answer (score 1):

Its likely that the dylib you are using supports both iOS devices and the iOS Simulator. While preparing an app for submission to Apple's App Store, you must remove code that isn't for iOS devices, and that applies to the x86-based architectures of the iOS Simulator.
Check out this article that shows some scripts to remove the unwanted architectures - http://ikennd.ac/blog/2015/02/stripping-unwanted-architectures-from-dynamic-libraries-in-xcode/